# postgresql full text search function syntax

Tags: postgresql, indexing, full-text-search

In postgres database we have a table table1 and with column column1 which type is text.
And we created an index to that column 
    CREATE INDEX idx_column1 ON table1 USING gin (to_tsvector('english', column1));

question is, why when we execute this query

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
where to_tsvector('english', column1) @@ to_tsquery('searchedText')
```

index is used, but by this query index is not used

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
where ts_match_vq(to_tsvector('english', column1),to_tsquery('searchedText'))
```

Comment: `ts_match_vq(to_tsvector('english', column1) @@ to_tsquery('searchedText'))` This does not work for me. The function is defined as expecting a ts_vector and a ts_query. In your example, you are passing a boolean to it, my 9.1 complains about this.

Comment: Sorry, corrected question. Instead of **ts_match_vq(to_tsvector('english', column1) @@ to_tsquery('searchedText'))** I wanted ask about **to_tsvector('english', column1) @@ to_tsquery('searchedText')**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wild guess:

`vector @@ query` is defined as

```
CREATE OPERATOR @@(
  PROCEDURE = ts_match_vq,
  LEFTARG = tsvector,
  RIGHTARG = tsquery,
  COMMUTATOR = @@,
  RESTRICT = tsmatchsel,
  JOIN = tsmatchjoinsel);
```

Looking at [`tsmatchjoinsel`](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ts__selfuncs_8c.html#aa84e1f2b060708a03149d055ffe28cc0) there is quite a lot going on (don't ask me what, this kind of C is way beyond me....) But if you go through the different functions, there are some calculations involved. When using  `ts_match_vq` directly, you bypass these calculations. That's why `ts_match_vq` is never mentioned in the docs and you should always use `@@` since it takes care of calling the right functions and all the stuff that goes with it.